# Combine FindFirstFile with GetFileSize / GetFileSizeEx to increase performance (kernel32)

Tags: c#, pinvoke, .net, kernel32

I'm using `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile (kernel32)` to get folders and files (`c# Pinvoke`).
`System.IO` is too slow and does not support path over 250 chars.

Is it possible to use the handle - in any way - returned by `FindNextFile` to get the byte length of a file?

Current try returns `INVALID_HANDLE`. I think the reason is the directory callback instead of the createfile callback.

I want to avoid to call `CreateFile` again to get the file handle "twice"; it's very slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Related https://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindNextFile` does not return a handle. Not sure why you think that would be the case.

`WIN32_FIND_DATA` contains the file size. This structure is being filled by `FindNextFile`.